# How to stick the footer to the bottom of the page?

Tags: footer

I need the site footer to sit across the bottom of the site at all times.

Currently, it sits across the site bottom when there is content on the page, but with no content on the page it (.site-footer) rises from the bottom to the middle of the visible page as represented in this image:

<kbd>[image: Footer in the middle of the screen]</kbd>

I was able to answer my own question and posted discovery process below:

Comment: Show some code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search shows this question has been asked and answered many times.

From StackOverflow: [Make footer stick to bottom of page correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443606/make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page-correctly)

From StackOverflow: [How to get the footer to stick to the bottom of your web page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

From CSS-Tricks: [5 different ways to make a sticky footer](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

From Code Pen: ["Always on the bottom" Footer](https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx)

From WordPress: [How to make footer fixed to the bottom of the screen?](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-footer-fixed-to-the-bottom-of-the-screen/)

**I used the WordPress answer for my answer:**

```
.site-footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   
}
```

<kbd>[image: Footer properly stuck to site floor.]</kbd>

Comment: I tried using `absolute` to no avail, changing to `fixed` worked - however it does mean scrolling will keep footer fixed, which kinda sucks

Answer (score 2):

Add CSS for your footer, it will fix the position of footer to the bottom of the page.

```
    .site-footer{
     position:fixed;
     bottom:0px;
     left:0px;
     right:0px;
     width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: It will fix the footer position to the bottom